# Media Mix Modeling: testing LightMMM or Robyn on specific dataset rather than ongoing basis

Tags: python, r, statistics, data, visualization

I'm currently scoping ideas for a student project in data analytics and wanted to build this around **Media Mix Modeling** through either **LightMMM** (in Python, unofficial Google library) or **Robyn** (in R, by Meta).

However MMMs usually run over time, with data inputs on a regular basis from the business (for ex updated daily, weekly, monthly or quarterly etc).

**My question is:** is it possible to use and test either LightMMM or Robyn on a specific, static time-range public dataset that I would for example find on Kaggle (for ex: only 2022 data, run retroactively)?
This is mainly coming from the fact that I obviously don't have access to regularly updated and enriched business data.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!